# Structuring a generic logistics system

Tags: c#

This is for a city builder game, but the framework is supposed to be useful for any request and send.
Basically, you have Suppliers and Requesters. When a requester is running low on what it needs, a request is lodged. Then each tick all requests are processed and appropriate suppliers send their stuff to the appropriate requester and everyone is happy.
What is doing my head in is trying to get it all done with generics. I'm pretty good with generics but haven't used them in a while so the solution is probably simple.
Here is some code:

```
public interface Requester<T> where T : Item
{
    bool NeedsToRequest();
    Request<T> LodgeRequest();
}

public interface Supplier<T> where T : Item
{
    void Supply(Request<T> request);
}

public class Request<T> where T : Item
{
    public Pile<T> Target;
    public int Amount;
}
```

All this gets centralized in a big mediator class which handles request making and fulfilling, among other things.

```
public abstract class ProductionHandler
{ 
    public List<Supplier<Item>> Suppliers;

    public List<Request<Item>> Requests;

    public abstract bool TryRequest<T>(Request<T> request) where T : Item

}
```

also relevant are:

```
public class Pile<T> : List<T> where T : Item
{

    public int Amount
    {
        get { return this.Count; }
    }

}
```

The big issue is here is sorting suppliers by the type of T. I want to get go through the list of Requests, get its type, find a matching type of supplier from the list, and process the request.
Another issue would be lets say you have "Flowers : Item" and "Rose : Flower" and "Sunflower : Flower". If something requests flowers you would want to send it either type, so just comparing types isn't going to be as easy in this scenario.
If anyone could link me to a good article or advise me how to get everything structured, that would be swell thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first step that could help further in the line, is to use variance, so that e.g. `Supplier<Rose>` could be cast to `Supplier<Flower>` and to  `Supplier<Item>` (and vice versa). But for that to work, Supplier would have to be an interface (`ISupplier<out T>` ). More info here : [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This way, you can keep a list of `ISupplier<Item>`, but make sure the suppliers are added strongly typed. Meaning the list only contains direct implementations of items such as `ISupplier<Rose>` or `ISupplier<Sunflower>`
Having the collection convertible, you can simply use `OfType<ISupplier<ItemType>>` to get the required suppliers.

To couple the request, there are several possibilities (e.g. have 2 types on ISupplier or have the interface expose another generic method with another type and let the supplier do the checking per added type), but imo the cleanest method is to use a contravariant interface for the Request (`IRequest<in T>` ), that can be used in the interface definition.

Example setup:

```
public interface ISupplier<out T> 
{
    int Supply(IRequest<T> request);
}

public interface IRequest<in T> //request is input and is contravariant so it can be used in the ISupplier definition. Roughly said it means that if a specific type is used, it can also be used as input for any child type
{
    int Amount{get;set;}
}

public abstract class ProductionHandlerBase
{ 
    public List<ISupplier<Item>> Suppliers = new List<ISupplier<Item>>(); //ISupplier is covariant so any more derrived type (than Item) is still valid 

    public IEnumerable<ISupplier<T>> GetSuppliers<T>() //helper function to make calls easier, but Suppliers could be used directly as well
    {
        return Suppliers.OfType<ISupplier<T>>();
    }

    public bool TryRequest<T>(IRequest<T> Request)
        where T:Item
    {
        //example implementation. (neither optimized or necessariy logical, but it does show the expected types are used)
        foreach(var sup in GetSuppliers<T>())
        {
            if(sup.Supply(Request) > 0 && Request.Amount == 0)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void TestOutput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Suppliers));
    }
}

class ProductionHandlerExample:ProductionHandlerBase{}


public class Request<T>:IRequest<T>{
    public int Amount{get;set;}
}

public abstract class Supplier<T>:ISupplier<T>{
    int pileAmount = 4; //just to have an example
    public int Supply(IRequest<T> request) //example implementation
    {
        int cnt = Math.Min(request.Amount, pileAmount);
        if(cnt==0)return 0;
        pileAmount -= cnt;
        request.Amount -=cnt;
        return cnt;
    }

    public override string ToString() {return $"{typeof(T).Name}(s): {pileAmount}"; }
}

//items
public abstract class Item{}
public abstract class Flower:Item{}
public class Rose:Flower{}
public class SunFlower:Flower{}
public class Car:Item{}

//suppliers
public class Florist:Supplier<Flower>{} //implementation can still be on a class, as long as the collections are based on the covariant interface
public class Rosy:Supplier<Rose>{}
public class CarDealer:Supplier<Car>{}
```

Example usage:

```
var p = new ProductionHandlerExample();
p.Suppliers.Add(new Florist());
p.Suppliers.Add(new Rosy());
p.Suppliers.Add(new CarDealer());

//p.GetSuppliers<Flower>() -> Florist, Rosy
//p.GetSuppliers<Rose>() -> Rosy
//p.GetSuppliers<Item>() -> all items  (Florist, Rosy, CarDealer)

//in the example setup, each supplier has a pile of 4
p.TestOutput(); //Flower(s): 4, Rose(s): 4, Car(s): 4
p.TryRequest(new Request<Rose>{Amount = 2}); //returns true 
p.TestOutput(); //Flower(s): 4, Rose(s): 2, Car(s): 4
p.TryRequest(new Request<Car>{Amount = 5}); //returns false, there are only 4 cars
p.TestOutput(); //Flower(s): 4, Rose(s): 2, Car(s): 0
p.TryRequest(new Request<Flower>{Amount = 5}); //returns true, stock of both florist and Roses are used
p.TestOutput(); //Flower(s): 0, Rose(s): 1, Car(s): 0
```

In this example implementation, no sub type checking is done. e.g. if the Flowers in florist may perhaps be Roses. That is because the example assumes the type of flower is not actually known. If it is known, it would be better to have a general `(I)Supplier` with a generic TryRequest method in which each implementation checks its own stock (`Pile.OfType<>` or such)

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but it doesn't fully solve my problem. The ISupplier<T>{} interface needs to have a Supply method like "int Supply(Request<T> request)" to supply requests that takes a type involving T. Can this be done?

Comment: It certainly can be done, but the best way depends on how the rest of the stores are setup. Generally speaking, I'd say the best way is to add a contravariant `IRequest<in T>` to the mix, and use that for the parameter in `Supply`. I've altered the example to reflect such a setup

Comment: Thanks, Although I've gotten around it by removing requests and having IRequesters interact directly with ISuppliers. The issue was getting IRequesters to generate requests of the appropriate type. Hard to explain, I'll try and put up a solution soon.

Comment: Update: first point, Trying to process things in the mediator class is silly, because you lose the information of what types you are dealing with, better off giving the Requesters or Supplier a reference to the mediator so it has access to all the info it needs. That way you sill have access to T. 

Point 2: Unity3D doesn't seems to work properly with covariance. Once you put a covariant type into an array you get errors, but this won't happen if using other C# things.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about your `TryRequest` method. In your `TryRequest<T>(Request<T> request) where T : Item` implementation, you have T, so you can go through `Suppliers` quite easily using reflection:

```
var supplier = Suppliers.FirstOrDefault
                   ( sup => sup.GetType()
                               .GenericTypeArguments[0] == typeof(T)
                   );
```

As you can see, this is not very pretty, but I don't have a better option at this time.

Comment: Some small additional notes for the OP: if `sup` is not a `Supplier<T>` directly but an implementer, (e.g. `Florist:Supplier<Flower>`), it (florist) will not have generic arguments itself (its `BaseType` would). Also this is a direct comparison on `typeof(T)` , so `Supplier<Rose>` would not match `<Flower>`. If that is the wish `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(....` could be used instead